# 'Today afternoon' vs 'Today in the afternoon'?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, grammaticality

Which adverbial phrase of time is more grammatically correct: 'Today afternoon' or 'Today in the afternoon'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neither are clauses, but "today in the afternoon" is grammatical (adverbial phrase of time), while "today afternoon" is not. I would also suggest "this afternoon" as a more succinct and idiomatic alternative to "today in the afternoon".

Comment: I suspect, from other discussions here, that "today afternoon" may be grammatical, and perhaps even idiomatic, in Indian English. It is certainly not in UK.

Comment: To clarify: I have not seen "today afternoon", but certainly "today morning" has come up, as being common in Indian English

Comment: *This afternoon* is definitely the way to go. You can say *Tuesday afternoon* or *yesterday afternoon*, but not *today afternoon*.

Comment: I have never heard anyone say "today afternoon", except perhaps in the context of a stutter or appositive. "Let's meet today -- afternoon -- and then we'll see where to go from there." Otherwise, it's ungrammatical.

Comment: Having worked with many Indians, 'today afternoon' is perfectly correct to them. In addition preponing a meeting (moving it forward) is also normal.